# Match a completed string with regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a string,

```
s = '`re.``search`(*pattern*, *string*, *flags=0*)',
```

Easily it produces such a result using `sub`

```
In [100]: re.sub(r'[`*]','',s)
Out[100]: 're.search(pattern, string, flags=0)'
```

I'd like to refactor it by writing a whole regex pattern instead of substituting.

```
In [101]: re.search(r'[^`*]+',s)
Out[101]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 4), match='re.'>
```

It stops at first match `'re.`, while I intend to retrieve the completed.

How to accomplish such a task?

Comment: Try `str.join` with `re.findall`: `''.join(re.findall(r'[^\`*]+',s))`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You cannot match disjoint string parts within one match operation. Substitution approach is only logical 1-step solution here. `re.search(r'[^\`*]+',s)` only finds the first chunk of 1+ chars other than `\`` and `*`.

Comment: I try to get `'re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)'` alternatively. @Maroun

Comment: @Computing Then I don't see anything wrong with your initial approach.

Comment: _"I'd like to refactor it by writing a whole regex pattern instead of substituting."_ Why? Using `re.sub` is the easiest and most straightforward solution.

Comment: @Maroun I am trying to find a solution as greedy `.`

Comment: @Rawing Trying to find a greedy solution.

Comment: Instead of regex you can use two replace method. Using regex which is recommended if the extra characters are more than that, and you're looking for use a general approach, the `re.sub` is a good choice. In addition, If you want to apply the regex on multiple strings you can compile the regex before applying on your strings.

Comment: Again, _why_? Do you want to get a different result than `"re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)"`?

Comment: dot `.` stops at `\n`, I attempt to let `[^*]`  do it @Rawing